# Не могу реализовать гамбургер меню при адаптиве на сайте

Tags: html, css

Всем здравствуйте ребята.

У меня такая проблема, вот у меня есть адаптивный сайт, и для него я сделал гамбургер меню, но почему то оно не работает, когда по ней кликаешь... Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой.

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот код на codepen : https://codepen.io/ibrahim2/pen/PdMVpa

Comment: Добавьте ваш пример и codepen в вопрос - редактировать сообщение - вставка кода(кнопка '<>')

Comment: Ну, так я же оставил ссылку на CodePen, где сейчас залит код моей вёрстки

Comment: Извиняюсь, опечатка = иЗ CodePen

Comment: То есть, весь код HTML/CSS/JS добавить сюда в StackOverflow

Comment: Да. [ask], [mcve], [Мой сайт/проект не работает. Можно я просто дам на него ссылку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5263/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D1%83/5264#5264)

Comment: Ну, ведь я дал ссылку на CodePen, где залит мой код верстки))